# What benefit does defining prop type offer in Vue3 (vue-class-component) when using typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Vue 3 with vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator in typescript. I can define a prop as

```
@Prop({}) readonly foo!: Foo;
```

This tells typescript that it is a Foo object and it tells Vue that it is a prop. But I can also define it like this:

```
@Prop({type: Foo}) readonly foo!: Foo;
@Prop({type: Object as PropType<Foo>}) readonly foo!: Foo;
```

I am not sure which of this is better/correct. The first one does get confused with Proxies (passing a Foo Proxy raises a warning), so I guess the second is actually correct. Except it doesn't raise a warning if I now pass a Bar object instead of a Foo. It actually doesn't seem to offer anything over the prop definition without the type.

Is there any reason to write out the type?

Comment: The second is the correct syntax.  I have never seen the first example ever even run.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the second line of the second code block should be used instead of the first line in the second code block. But my main question is how does this differ from the first code block?